# I want to update mysql vertion 5.5.59 to 5.7.21

Tags: linux, mysql-5.7

I'm trying to update my mysql version but it showing error I'm using Linux mint 17.3 version

**used command**

sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7

it showing this

```
  Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package mysql-client-core-5.7 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  mysql-cluster-community-client:i386 libmysqlclient-dev:i386
  mysql-community-client:i386 mysql-cluster-community-client
  libmysqlclient-dev mysql-community-client

Package mysql-server-core-5.7 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  mysql-common:i386 mysql-cluster-community-server:i386
  mysql-community-server:i386 mysql-common mysql-cluster-community-server
  mysql-community-server

E: Package 'mysql-server-core-5.7' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'mysql-client-core-5.7' has no installation candidate
```

> mysql -v

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.59, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3
```

how can i fix this??

Comment: I'm no apt-get expert but I think `apt-get purge` will uninstall package, not install.

Comment: Also, most important: before beginning any update work and before running any command, have you taken a **back up of your databases?**

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ thanks for the advice .that my mistake i'm edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, never try to uninstall or purge your mysql packages. Your db be drop from your system for ever…**

Secondly, you should try to use `apt-cache policy mysql*` to check which versions are available on your system.

Thirdly, you should do a backup of ALL you DB.

If it is a simple update, you should try `sudo apt-get upgrade mysql-client mysql-server mysql-common`.

Or more aggressive `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade mysql-client mysql-server mysql-common`

If not, use the version available for update from `apt-cache policy mysql*` output.

And, from what I can see, your source.list seems not to contain any repo that contains `mysql-server-core-5.7`. So use `apt-cache policy mysql*`.